# Very weird reactivity issue with firebase (firestore) and vuejs + vuefire

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

i am having some really weird issue and i am totally stuck.

i have this component:

```
<template>
  <v-card elevation="0">
    <h2>Accounts</h2>
    <v-simple-table fixed-header height="300px">
      <template v-slot:default>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-left">Account ID</th>
            <th class="text-left">Broker</th>
            <th class="text-left">Balance</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="account in accounts" :key="account.accountId">
            <td>{{ account.accountId }}</td>
            <td>{{ account.broker }}</td>
            <td>{{ accountBalances[account.accountId] }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </template>
    </v-simple-table>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
import { DB } from "../../firebase/db";

export default {
  name: "Accounts",
  data: () => ({
    cashTransactions: [],
    accounts: [],
    newAccount: []
  }),
  computed: {
    accountBalances: function() {
      try {
        let balances = {};
        this.accounts.forEach(account => {
          let accBal = 0;
          const transactions = this.cashTransactions.filter(acc => {
            return acc.accountId === account.accountId;
          });
          transactions.forEach(transaction => {
            accBal += Number(transaction.amount);
          });
          balances[account.accountId] = accBal;
        });
        return balances;
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return err;
      }
    }
  },
  firestore: {
    cashTransactions: DB.collection("cashTransactions"),
    accounts: DB.collection("accounts")
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

and this firestore collections:

[image: Firestore Collections]

when i define the firestore inside my components like this:

```
  firestore: {
    cashTransactions: DB.collection("cashTransactions"),
    accounts: DB.collection("accounts")
  }
```

only the accounts property is reactive - as in, i add a document to the collection, it gets updated in real time (sorta).

if i define it like this:

```
  data: () => ({
    accounts: [],
    cashTransactions: [],
    newAccount: []
  }),
  firestore: {
    accounts: DB.collection("accounts"),
    cashTransactions: DB.collection("accounts")
  }
```

also only accounts is reactive.

if i define it like this:

```
  data: () => ({
    accounts: [],
    cashTransactions: [],
    newAccount: []
  }),
  firestore: {
    accounts: DB.collection("cashTransactions"),
    cashTransactions: DB.collection("accounts")
  }
```

accounts is reactive with the cashTransactions-collection-data, the cashTransactions property (with accounts-collection-data) is still not reactive

if i set it back to

```
  data: () => ({
    accounts: [],
    cashTransactions: [],
    newAccount: []
  }),
  firestore: {
    accounts: DB.collection("accounts"),
    cashTransactions: DB.collection("cashTransactions")
  }
```

the accounts property is reactive with accounts-collection-data while the cashTransactions property remains non-reactive

so, regardless of what i do, the cashTransactions property is non-reactive and only "refreshes" on a page refresh.

has anyone an idea what i am doing wrong?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following as a workaround after `firestore():{}`

```
watch: {
    cashTransactions(): {
        deep: true,
        handler(newArray) {
            console.log( 'Change detected...' );
        } 
    },
}
```

Hope this helps.